# Custom Tags Support with Java EE

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, custom-tag

Given the following HTML in a Java EE environment:

```
<input name="foo" value="hello" />
```

I would expect `ServletRequest.getParameterNames()` would include `foo`.

However given for example:

```
<footag name="foo" value="hello"/>
```

I would hopefully expect `ServletRequest.getParameterNames()` to include `foo` but it doesn't. This leads me to ponder:

1. Why is it that the `ServletRequest` accepts the value from the input tag but not my custom tag?
2. Am I right in assuming that HTML5 supports this kind of extensibility?
3. Does anyone know exactly which tags `ServletRequest` accepts for parameter binding?

Comment: I never heard about custom tags in HTML5, I doubt that I is possible.  I will question vote up, maybe I will get know something new.

Comment: It's not about `ServletRequest`, it's about your browser as that is responsible for transferring HTTP requests. AFAIK what you're trying to achieve is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation into this it turns out that it was in fact the browser that was not sending form parameter. According to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/forms.html#categories):

> Submittable elements:
>
> Denotes elements that can be used for constructing the form data set when a form element is submitted.
>
> button, input, keygen, object, select, textarea

It seems that only these tags should supply posted data. So it was not the `RequestServlet` that is causing the problem.